# Mysql add time based on conditions

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime, sum, datediff

I have one table whose structure is like as follows

```
 +---------------------+---------+
| date_time           | portNo1 |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2016-01-08 13:15:46 |       1 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:16:01 |       2 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:16:16 |       1 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:16:31 |       2 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:16:46 |       1 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:17:00 |       2 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:17:16 |       1 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:17:31 |       1 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:17:46 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:18:01 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:18:16 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:18:31 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:18:41 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:19:01 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:19:16 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:19:27 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:19:41 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:19:56 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:20:11 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:20:26 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:20:41 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:20:56 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:21:16 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:21:31 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:21:43 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:22:01 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:22:16 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:22:31 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:22:46 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:23:01 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:23:12 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:23:31 |       0 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:23:46 |       2 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:24:01 |       2 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:24:16 |       2 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:24:31 |       1 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:24:46 |       2 | 
| 2016-01-08 13:25:00 |       2 |
```

Now what I have to do is only add the time whose `portNo1` value is not `0`
that means it should add time from `13:15:46` to `13:17:31` in seconds then since after that all record till `13:23:46` value is `0` it should ignore that time and continue. then again from `13:23:46` has `portNo1` value it should take difference between `13:23:46` and `13:23:31` and add it to the previous difference. Guys I tried lot in perl to do it but not getting correct values if there is any easy way in mysql please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm understanding the question all wrong, you can do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(prevtime))
FROM (
   SELECT date_time, portNo1, @prevTime as prevtime,
     @prevTime := date_time
   FROM MyTable
) t1 
WHERE (portNo1 > 0 AND prevtime IS NOT null)
```

This will sum the time differences (in seconds) between the current row and the previous row if the `portNo1` in the current row is greater than 0. Is this what you want?

I've made a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6dfa/3

Comment: it says Unknown column 'time' in 'field list'

Comment: Use your column names in the inner query

Comment: I have column with name date_time..I added that in inner query still it is giving me same error.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time)-TIME_TO_SEC(CAST(prevtime AS TIME))) FROM (    SELECT date_time, portNo1, @prevTime as prevtime, @prevTime := date_time    FROM tracklog_2_1_pulse_history ) t1  WHERE (portNo1 > 0 AND prevtime IS NOT null);`

Comment: `SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time)` should be `SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(date_time)` in this case

Comment: your fiddle is correct only problem is my date_time column contains date as well as time so it is giving me Null,. The query you post executed but the output was NULL

Comment: @element well, i'm based on the question you posted. Edit your question and specify your requirements correctly. You put a column with only time there

Comment: I am sorry I will just edit my question..I have edited the question pls reply

Comment: I've updated the answer (and the fiddle): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6dfa/2 to handle `datetime`. All the basics remain

Comment: @eLemEnt as a disclaimer, I *think* the results are correct, but your question is a bit convoluted so I'm not sure if I'm handling all the possible cases correctly. Make a manual check against your requirements (make a manual sum of seconds in a small dataset which handles all possible cases, and then run the query over that dataset and see if it gives the same result).